# Replace a tag if it exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm dynamically appending an `input` tag inside a `div` tag when i click on a button, so it may happen that the same tag is duplicated in that div. What i want to do is to replace the existing one by the new one. My code is as follows:

```
<div id="data" name="data"></div>
<input type=button value="+ Ajouter Element" onclick="ajouter();">

<script>
function ajouter() {   
    for(k=0;k<i;k++) {
        h=$("#hauteur"+(k+1)).val();
        l=$("#largeur"+(k+1)).val();
        p=$("#position"+(k+1)).val();
        ch+='<div style="width: '+l+'%; height: '+h+'%; border-style:solid; float:'+p+' "></div>';
        $("#data").append('<input type="hidden" name="div'+(k+1)+'" id="div'+(k+1)+'" value="'+(k+1)+';'+h+';'+l+';'+p+'">');}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well i found it by myself :

```
if($("#div"+(k+1)).length == 0) {
    $("#data").append('<input type="hidden" name="div'+(k+1)+'" id="div'+(k+1)+'" value="'+(k+1)+';'+h+';'+l+';'+p+'">');
} else {
    $("#data").find("#div"+(k+1)).replaceWith('<input type="hidden" name="div'+(k+1)+'" id="div'+(k+1)+'" value="'+(k+1)+';'+h+';'+l+';'+p+'">');
}
```

Hope this helps anyone in need for it :)

Comment: I guess this means you posted the question too soon or you had the answer when posting the question ;-)

Comment: @Maroua Gasmi : For the second case, I would suggest 2 improvements : since, `"div" + (k+1)` is an unique id and that you know it exists (the test is on its existence), you should directly find it and the second thing is to modify only what has to be modified. It will lead to this code: `$("#div"+(k+1)).value((k+1)+';'+h+';'+l+';'+p);`

Comment: @jan dvorak: well for some kind of reason the forum delayed accepting my question for 20 minutes the time it took me to find out the solution ;)

Comment: @Samuel Caillerie: thank you for the improvements, especially for the second part :)